# Filter query results using subquery - single table

Tags: sql

I have one table where I need all rows that meet the criteria in the first query (MIS), but only need to include 'EMP' if EMPID <92.  I'm sure it's a simple statement, but I can't figure it out.  Help!

```
SELECT MIS.*
FROM

(SELECT EMPID, ORG, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, JCODE, DPTID, TITLE, STATUS, BU, LOC, CO, SUP_ID, AL_EMPID
    FROM EMPLOYEE_TBL
    WHERE REHIRE_ELIG <> 'Y'
      AND HIRE_OVR <> 'Y'
      AND SUP_ID IS NOT NULL
      AND JCODE IS NOT NULL
      AND ORG IN ('EMP','CWD')) MIS
      WHERE MIS.ORG = 'EMP'
        AND EMPID < '9200000'
  ORDER BY MIS.ORG DESC, MIS.JCODE ASC
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Why not just add `AND empid < 92`?

Comment: Is it `EMP` a table?

Comment: What version and flavor of SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a left outer join.
Something like:
select *
from table1 mis left outer join table1 msi2
on mis.id=mis2.id
where mis2.empid<92

Then anything in in mis2 is an id<92.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `OR` in the `WHERE`. My setup was done in SQL 2017, but that is fairly standard syntax and should work in any flavor of SQL.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/165299/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_tbl ( 
    EMPID int
  , ORG varchar(5)
  , other_stuff varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO employee_tbl (EMPID, ORG, other_stuff)
VALUES 
    ( 90000000, 'EMP', 'IncludeMe' )
  , ( 91000000, 'EMP', 'IncludeMe' )
  , ( 91000001, 'CWD', 'IncludeMe' )
  , ( 91000002, 'EMP', 'IncludeMe' )
  , ( 92000000, 'EMP', 'ExcludeMe' )
  , ( 95000000, 'EMP', 'ExcludeMe' )
;
```

**Main Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee_tbl
WHERE ( ORG = 'EMP' AND EMPID < 92000000 )
    OR ( ORG = 'CWD' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/165299/1/0)**:

```
|    EMPID | ORG | other_stuff |
|----------|-----|-------------|
| 90000000 | EMP |   IncludeMe |
| 91000000 | EMP |   IncludeMe |
| 91000001 | CWD |   IncludeMe |
| 91000002 | EMP |   IncludeMe |
```